# Transforming Quaternion to Camera rotation matrix - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, quaternions

I've been trying to warp a couple of photos with exact Quaternions for weeks without luck. The equation below doesn't seem to rotate the camera position as well as I'd expect from exact positions. Am I doing it right? Is there something I'm missing?

I understand that simply passing a Quaternion is not enough to stitch a photo, but it should be enough to align the photos?

Here's the formula:

```
double divmult = 2.0 / lsq;
double xx = divmult * x * x;
double yy = divmult * y * y;
double zz = divmult * z * z;

double wx = divmult * w * x;
double wy = divmult * w * y;
double wz = divmult * w * z;
double xy = divmult * x * y;
double xz = divmult * x * z;
double yz = divmult * y * z;

cameras_global[imageCounter].R = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << ( 1 - yy - zz ),    -( xy - wz ),   -( xz + wy ),
                                  ( xy + wz ),        -( 1 -xx -zz ), -( yz - wx ),
                                  ( xz - wy ),        -( yz + wx ),   -( 1 -xx -yy )   );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV does not directly support quaternions. Rather than fixing your calculations, I would go with a simpler conversion. The closest thing it has is axis-angle vectors to represent 3D rotations (also named Rodrigues angles). I would [convert to axis-angle](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/), then multiply the axis by the angle to obtain Rodrigues angles. After that, you can use OpenCV's built-in functions, for instance [cv::Rodrigues](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues) to convert to a 3x3 rotation matrix.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the link you've referenced seems to be doing the opposite of what you're saying. It seems to be converting angular velocity to a quaternion?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! One last question, (sorry in advance if its a noob question), but - after I convert the quaternion -> rodrigues angles, do I use the return from rodrigues to camera_global[0].R? Or what do I do with the angles?

Comment: Rodrigues(v, camera_global[0].R)

Comment: please check my latest question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861985/refining-camera-parameters-and-calculating-errors-opencv , you can see the results there from simply passing the equation above. Is that considered "good"? Or will I get more accurate results from converting to Rodrigues?