# Refining Camera parameters and calculating errors - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to refine my camera parameters with `CvLevMarq` but after reading about it, it seems to be causing mixed results - which is exactly what I am experiencing. I read about the alternatives and came upon `EIGEN` - and also found [this library](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/panorama/blob/master/src/stitch/incremental_bundle_adjuster.cc) that utilizes it.

However, the library above seems to use a stitching class that doesn't support `OpenCV` and will probably require me to port it to `OpenCV`.

Before going ahead and doing so, which will probably not be an easy task, I figured I'd ask around first and see if anyone else had the same problem?

**I'm currently using:**

**1.** Calculating features with `FASTFeatureDetector`

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = new FastFeatureDetector(5,true);
detector->detect(firstGreyImage, features_global[firstImageIndex].keypoints); // Previous picture
detector->detect(secondGreyImage, features_global[secondImageIndex].keypoints); // New picture
```

**2.** Extracting features with `SIFTDescriptorExtractor`

```
Ptr<SiftDescriptorExtractor> extractor = new SiftDescriptorExtractor();
extractor->compute(firstGreyImage, features_global[firstImageIndex].keypoints, features_global[firstImageIndex].descriptors); // Previous Picture
extractor->compute(secondGreyImage, features_global[secondImageIndex].keypoints, features_global[secondImageIndex].descriptors); // New Picture
```

**3.** Matching features with `BestOf2NearestMatcher`

```
vector<MatchesInfo> pairwise_matches;
BestOf2NearestMatcher matcher(try_use_gpu, 0.50f);
matcher(features_global, pairwise_matches);
matcher.collectGarbage();
```

**4.** `CameraParams.R` quaternion passed from a device (slightly inaccurate which causes the issue)

**5.** `CameraParams.Focal` == 389.0f -- Played around with this value, 389.0f is the only value that matches the images horizontally but not vertically.

**6.** [Bundle Adjustment](https://github.com/BubblePix/PanoramaStitching/blob/master/PanoramaStitching/Stitching/BPRefiner.cpp) (`cvLevMarq`, `calcError` & `calcJacobian`)

```
Ptr<BPRefiner> adjuster = new BPRefiner();
adjuster->setConfThresh(0.80f);
adjuster->setMaxIterations(5);
(*adjuster)(features,pairwise_matches,cameras);
```

**7.** `ExposureCompensator` (GAIN)

**8.** OpenCV `MultiBand Blender`

**What works so far:**

- `SeamFinder` - works to some extent but it depends on the result of the `cvLevMarq` algoritm. I.e. if the algoritm is off, `seamFinder` is going to be off too.
- `HomographyBasedEstimator` works beautifully. However, since it "relies" on the features, it's unfortunately not the method that I'm looking for.

I wouldn't want to rely on the features since I already have the matrix, if there's a way to "refine" the current matrix instead - then that would be the targeted result.

**Results so far:**

`cvLevMarq` "Russian roulette" 6/10:

This is what I'm trying to achieve 10/10 times. But 4/10 times, it looks like the picture below this one.

[image]

By simply just re-running the algorithm, the results change. 4/10 times it looks like this (or worse):

`cvLevMarq` "Russian roulette" 4/10:

[image]

**Desired Result:**

I'd like to "refine" my camera parameters with the features that I've matched - in hope that the images would align perfectly. Instead of hoping that `cvLevMarq` will do the job for me *(which it won't 4/10 times)*, is there another way to ensure that the images will be aligned?

**Update:**

I've tried these versions:

**OpenCV 3.1:** Using `CVLevMarq` with 3.1 is like playing Russian roulette. Some times it can align them perfectly, and other times it estimates focal as NAN which causes segfault in the MultiBand Blender (ROI = 0,0,1,1 because of `NAN`)

**OpenCV 2.4.9/2.4.13:** Using `CvLevMarq` with 2.4.9 or 2.4.13 is unfortunately the same thing minus the `NAN` issue. 6/10 times it can align the images perfectly, but the other 4 times it's completely off.

**My Speculations / Thoughts:**

- [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html#gsc.tab=0) using OpenCV. Maybe if I template match the ends of the images (i.e. x = 0, y = 0,height = image.height, width = 50). Any thoughts about this?
- I found [this](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/computervision/ECE661.08/solution/hw5_s2.pdf) interesting paper about Levenberg Marquardt applied in Homography. That looks like something that could solve my problem since the paper uses corner detection and whatnot to detect the features in the images. Any thoughts about this?
- Maybe the problem isn't in `CvLevMarq` but instead in `BestOf2NearestMatcher`? However, I've searched for days and I couldn't find another method that returns the pairwise matches to pass to `BPRefiner`.
- [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) Detecting the lines in the first/second image and use that to align the images. Any thoughts on this? -- One thing might be, what if the images doesn't have any lines? I.e. empty wall?
- Maybe I'm overkilling something so simple.. Or maybe I'm not? Basically, I'm trying to align a set of images so I can warp them without overlapping each-other. Drop a comment if it doesn't make sense :)

**Update Aug 12:**

After trying all kinds of combinations, the absolute best so far is `CvLevMarq`. The only problem with it is the mixed results shown in the images above. If anyone has any input, I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: What is your setup and goal? How are the pictures taken? What is your precise question? If this is a merge of a binocular system, I would say the parameters could are wide off and could even be tuned by hand.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. I'm still kinda new to this field. Anyhow, the images are taken with approximately ~24 degrees difference, and the goal is to align them. Instead of using quaternions, I've instead implemented the actual matrix for higher precision. By playing around with the camera focal parameter I ended up using `camera_global[i].Focal = 418.0f` which makes it look aligned horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: So far, `SeamFinder` is the only thing that removes the overlapping but unfortunately leave its mark.

Comment: I've also tried using `CvLevMarq` & `calcJacobian` without luck. Although it can align the images, the results are unpredictable.

Comment: Maybe the way to go is using something like this> http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html#gsc.tab=0? @SpamBot

Comment: To level the images I mean

Comment: Or perhaps: `BestOf2NearestRangeMatcher`?

Comment: what do you mean by "align perfectly"? two different pictures will never overlay each other perfectly, as you can see on the "with `SeamFinder` picture, they are aligned in one part, but the rest has to be different, as the pictures differ. Or did I not understand you at all? :)

Comment: Let me update the pictures to clear out some of the confusion :) @slawekwin

Comment: Let me know if my update cleared things up.. @slawekwin

Comment: Yes, I think it is clearer now. However, the pictures are very different if you ask me (framed differently). Why is the change so drastic? It looks like you used different picture as a base to merge the other one into every other time. Maybe this is consistent in some way and you can select the frame with better result as base? This is basically a guess at this point, though.

Comment: I'm taking the images with about ~24 degrees distance. You're saying to lower the degrees to allow more features? @slawekwin

Comment: In short, my goal is to align & warp X amounts of images based on as much degree distance as possible. Thus being able to create a panorama picture with the least amount of pictures. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, I don't think this will change anything.. I'm still finding about ~800 features per picture and that should be enough to align them..

Comment: show how you're initializing `cameras`, probably your problem is there if `cvLevMarq` is giving garbage sometimes.

Comment: wrote my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your parameter initialization is the problem. I would use a linear estimator first, i.e. ignore your noisy sensor, and then use this as the initial values for the non-linear optimizer.

A quick method is to use [`getaffinetransform`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getaffinetransform), as you have mostly rotation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions of a linear estimator? And/or any example implementation that I could reference? @fireant

Comment: P.S, you might ask.. Why is the the quaternion "slightly inaccurate"? And that problem roots back to the iOS Core Motion SDK which is basically not perfected enough to give exact values.

Comment: @Cookies that's good know! you would guess the gyroscope is accurate for a short span of time . updated the answer, but there is really a lot of options for doing this, should see which is robust enough for your application, e.g. using ransac...

Comment: You'd think that they'd perfect it after it was introduced first in `iOS 5.0`.. But no.. Anyhow, sorry for the following noob question but, what do I pass in to `getAffineTransform`? Looks like it takes `Point2f` as source & destination, but that really doesn't make any sense to me. Is there any further documentation on this? Or do you mind explaining?

Comment: google should find a few tutorials. explaining how it works is really lengthy. just find three points that are not collinear and their correspondences in the second image.

Comment: e.g., see https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/

Comment: I see, so you're just using `std::vector< Point2f > obj;` & `std::vector< Point2f > scene;` to `getAffineTransform` ?

Comment: yep, that should do

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just implemented `getAffineTransform` and was faced with assertions because the features are not exactly 3 correspondents. So after some Googling I found to use `findHomography` instead, but that method terminates when I pass it into `warper->warpRoi(img.size(), K, foundHomography[0]);` Any clues of how to solve this?

Comment: Question.. Can't I just pass back `findHomography` to `cameras[0].R` or `.t`? No? Should I do some more reading before sounding too dumb? :P

Comment: well you can open new questions, as you already found what was wrong with your solution. you can extract the camera rotation matrix and translation vector from homography. i remember a while ago i answered a question regarding that here. so there should be plenty of material covering that.

Comment: i meant yes, that's what you should do after the initial estimation then can run the non-linear optimization.

Comment: What's the difference between `getAffineTransformation` & `findHomography`? If I only pass in 3 features to `getAffineTransformation`, is it better to use? Secondly, how can you ever only get 3 features from an image? I average ~400.. Lastly, I've been trying to `decomposeHomography ` with the method in OpenCV 3.1 then using `Zhang` or `Inria` to get the best out of the 4 returned possible matches -- is this correct? Seems like `decomposeHomography` is 3D?

Comment: P.S, I opened up a new question regarding this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940389/estimating-r-t-from-homography

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at this library: https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr.

Cheers

Comment: Looks pretty cool! But not sure where to get the ROS values from?

Comment: What ROS values are you talking about, you can also install it without the need of ROS, see here: https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/wiki/installation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but by using it you have to generate ROS bag values using either a sensor or bagcreator script. Either way, seems to be an overkill? Or maybe I'm just terribly wrong -- in which case, could you explain how this would benefit me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stitch the images, you should see [stitching_detailed.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp). It will probably solve your problem.

In addition, I have used Graph Cut Seam Finding method with Canny Edge Detection for better stitching results in this code. If you want to optimize this code, see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-panorama-stitching).

Also, if you are going to use it for personal use, SIFT is good. You should know, SIFT is patented and will cost you if you use it for commercial purposes. Use ORB instead.

Hope it helps!