# Estimating R/T from Homography

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to calculate the features in 2 images and then pass those features back to `CameraParams.R` without luck. The features are calculated and matched successfully, however, the problem is passing them back to `R & t`.

I understand that you must decompose the `Homography` in order for this to be possible, which I've done using something like this: https://github.com/syilma/homography-decomp, but am I really doing it right?

Right now I'm simply using:

**Matching:**

```
vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create(algorithmName);
matcher->knnMatch( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 50 );

vector< DMatch > good_matches; // Storing good matches here
```

I've noticed that the `good_matches` isn't used anywhere. So I guess my question is, how can I pass back `good_matches` to `cameras.R/t`?

**Extracting Homography:**

```
Mat K;
cameras[img_idx].K().convertTo(K, CV_32F);

findHomography -> decomposeHomography(H, K, outputR,outputT,noarray()).
```

Then by utilizing the library above, I pass in the values from `R` & `t` but the response is that the homography isn't found in the 4 possible outcomes.

Am I on the right path here? Seems like decomposeHomography is a 3D solution, but, findHomography is 2D?

**Absolute Goal:**

Refine `CameraParam.R/t` depending on the features found in the images.

Why? Because I'm currently passing in the `.R` from the devices rotation matrix but the rotation is slightly inaccurate. See more info about it on my previous question: [Refining Camera parameters and calculating errors - OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861985/refining-camera-parameters-and-calculating-errors-opencv/38924445)

Comment: I'm curious to know  if it is better with this code (https://github.com/LaurentBerger/TestHomograhy)

Comment: I'll try it out! Thanks @LBerger

Comment: Quick question, I've been reading the OpenCV documentation in & out and found a few interesting functions that might help me achieve my goal. What are you thoughts about `calibrateCamera`/`calibrationMatrixValues`/`solvePNP` ? @LBerger

Comment: `solvePNP` is the function that makes the most sense to me. However, I'm not sure where to get `distCoeffs` from.. Or should I just stick to my original approach? I.e. Finding & matching the features -> decomposing homography -> pass back to `.R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the calculated R for image stitching, then there is no need to use decompose homography. Whole stitching pipeline assumes zero translation. So it gives perfect output for  only rotation case and slight error is introduced with the introduction of translation in camera pose. If you look into opencv calculation of R from homography, it assumes 0 translation.

```
Mat R = K_from.inv() * pairwise_matches[pair_idx].H.inv() * K_to;
cameras[edge.to].R = cameras[edge.from].R * R;
```

You can find the source code in motion_estimators.cpp ->calcRotation function.
Coming to your question of using goodmatches for calculating R. goodmatches are actually used to calculate homography matrix, using *findhomography* function

So the whole process will be like

1. Find matches (as you mentioned)
2. Find homography matrix from these matches using *findhomography*
   function
3. Use *calcrotation* function to find R
4. Find focal using *findfocalfromhomography* function and create intrinsic matrix
5. Use warper, seamfinder and blender for final stitching output

Comment: I love how you are scanning through all of my questions and answering them with intelligence :) Thank you!